# What is the function of emptyList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Why there is such emptyList constructor in Kotlin?
It was a immutable List, so there is no way to add or remove its elements and it was empty!
So, what is the function of this emptyList?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [`emptyList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html) is not a constructor but a function that returns and immutable empty list implementation.

The main reason such function exists is to save allocations. Since `emptyList` returns the same **singleton** instance every time it is called so one can use it in allocation free manner. Note that the very same object is returned regardless of the element type i.e. `emptyList<String>() === emptyList<Int>()` is `true`.

IMHO `emptyList` also reads a bit better than `listOf` when used as e.g. a default parameter value:

```
data class Person(val friends:List<Person> = emptyList())
```

Comment: And the reason it has to be a function (instead of just exposing the underlying singleton object instance directly) is that it couldn't be generic otherwise: You want to use the same instance for empty String lists and empty BigDecimal lists. This works because you are never going to get any objects out of an empty list, so it is perfectly type-safe that way.

Comment: I don't think this the correct use of the term "singleton". It has only one of multiple things in common with singletons. I think this answer could be improved by avoiding possible confusions with singletons (e.g. that every encapsulated const/final variable is a singleton).

Comment: I was wondering about the differences between using emptyList() and listOf() and came across this answer that clarifies exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

@miensol provides a good answer addressing the lower-level details of using a singleton empty list object, minimizing allocations. In my opinion, the allocation of an empty list in JVM-based language is only marginally significant. You will be losing a few bytes of memory or wasting only a few clock cycles when instantiating via `listOf()`. Of course, if you create empty lists all of the time, this may add up, but it's difficult for me to see where this is applicable.

While I do not know the design intent of the API, I definitely see a ***semantic*** reason for its inclusion.
As @miensol already stated, `emptyList()` appears like a good candidate for a default parameter. The reason this is true is because it adheres to the well-known [Null-Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

Briefly, the pattern suggests a design where we use semantically meaningful types to represent our empty, default, or null values. In languages susceptible to null-pointer exceptions, this is useful because a proper object allows the client to call any of the available class members.

Consider the example below, where we use a default of `null`.

```
class AcademicProfile(val courseGradesAsPercent : List<Double>? = null) {

    fun displayAverage() {
        if (courseGradesAsPercent == null)
            println("No average to calculate, please sign-up for a course!")
        else {
            val sum = courseGradesAsPercent.reduce { accumulator, value -> accumulator + value }
            val average = sum / courseGradesAsPercent.count()
            println("Your unweighted average is $average")
        }
    }
}
```

The intent expressed by this class is that the list of course grades can be in any of the following states:

- null
- not-null, but empty
- filled with elements

Now, suppose we used `emptyList()` instead as the default:

```
class AcademicProfile(val courseGradesAsPercent : List<Double> = emptyList()) {

    fun displayAverage() {
        if (courseGradesAsPercent.isEmpty())
            println("No average to calculate, please sign-up for a course!")
        else {
            val sum = courseGradesAsPercent.reduce { accumulator, value -> accumulator + value }
            val average = sum / courseGradesAsPercent.count()
            println("Your unweighted average is $average")
        }
    }
}
```

In this scenario, there is no confusion between `null` and empty. If there are no grades, then the list is empty. These semantics are carried into the function by allowing us to call a member on the null-object's type (i.e. `List<Double>.isEmpty()`). Working with `null` expresses less about the domain and instead relies on the language's mechanics.

The performance benefit of using the singleton empty list is just icing on the cake!

Answer (score 6):

To address

> Actually i want to know why people using emptyList? What for?

more directly: you need it e.g. to pass to methods taking lists, or when you have a list which is empty in one branch of your code and not another:

```
val commandLineOptions: List<String> = when {
    x > 0 -> listOf(...)
    else -> emptyList()
}

runCommand(command, commandLineOptions)
```

Comment: Just one good example. It's also common for unit tests when you need to check for behaviour when inputs don't contain any elements...

Answer (score -4):

Actually，even if you declare an empty list，you can still add elements to this empty list by using the `"+"`, because Kotlin override some operators in its libraries:

```
var l = emptyList<Int>() 
print(l + 1) // output [1]
```

Comment: You're not adding to the original empty list, you're using it as the starting point and creating a new list with whatever you added to it.  In practice, it's similar, but still an important distinction.